# load image in an image view when table view(as popover) cell is selected

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview, uipopovercontroller

My storyboard application flows like this:

When a button(let me call it **"BtnA"**) is clicked it loads a table view(Let me call it **"TblA"**).

Once clicked on particular cell, a corresponding image(**"ImgA"**) will be loaded in a image view.

On image view's top bar there is another button(let me call it **"BtnB"**).When I click on the button(**BtnB**) one table view(Let me call it **"TblB"**) as popover is loaded; And, its cell values as same as the previously loaded tableview(**"TblA"**) cell(that is tableview loaded after my initial button click).

Now, What I want is, when popover tableview(**"TblB"**) cell is selected I want to load my corresponding image(**"ImgA"**) back to the image view.How Can I do this?

Note: .Button(**"BtnB"**) is connected tableview(**"TblB"**) as popover segue.

I was referring to this([load images in an image view from a table in a popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675123/load-images-in-an-image-view-from-a-table-in-a-popover) ), but, its seems that its bit different as its loading tableview's cell image to the image view.

Hope my question explanation is understandable.Please help.

Comment: You can use delegation to let TblA know when a cell is selected, and you can pass whatever as a parameter. So you create a protocol in TblB, set TblA as the delegate of TblB, implement delegate method in TblA, and when a cell is selected in TblB, you call the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegation in this case. What you can is, create a protocol in TblB controller

```
@protocol TblBDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)didSelectCellWithImage:(UIImage*)image
@end
```

I passed the image here, but you can pass whatever you need.

You create a delegate property in TblB

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id< TblBDelegate> delegate
```

Now you said you are presenting TblB popover with a segue. So in TblA, you implement prepareForSegue method and set TblA controller as the delegate

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SEGUE NAME"]) {
        TblBController *controller = (TblBController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Now in your TblA controller, you conform to protocol TblBDelegate, and implement the method

```
@interface TblAController <TblBDelegate>

@end
```

and in your .m file

```
-(void)didSelectCellWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    // Update your imageView with new image
}
```

and in your TblB controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get selected image
    // and call your delegate method
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectCellWithImage:)]) {
        [self.delegate didSelectCellWithImage:selectedImage]
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: There are two things: 1. My TblB's cell doesn't have any image; 2.My segue connection is like this->tableview(TblA) connected to imageview(ImgA) using segue,And, in image view I have a button to load another table view(TblB) using popover segue.Please look at your "- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender"

Comment: 1. It was just an example. You have to return some value that makes sense to let TblA know about the selection. You can pass anything back. 2. What do you mean tblA is connected to ImgA using segue? View Controllers are connected with segues, not views. And again doesn't matter where your button is, it is the view controller the that manages the view the button is in, that will be performing the segue. So in your case, probably you have UITableViewController that has TblA inside it. When you press the button, UITableViewController is performing the segue